# Good material to study analytic number theory

Tags: analytic-number-theory, online-resources

Can anyone suggest me a good resource to read analytic number theory. Videos are also welcome. I am looking for something that would be simple enough to understand.. especially

I. Arithmetical functions.
II. Characters of finite abelian groups.
III. Riemann Zeta function and Dirichlet L-functions.
IV. Dirichlet’s Theorem on primes in arithmetic progression.
V. Prime Number Theorem and related topics.
VI. Modular forms (for SL2(Z)). I am looking for these.. It would be better if I can get a video tutorial alongwith studying a book

Comment: Apostol wrote a book on analytic number theory

Comment: https://smile.amazon.com/gp/product/0387901639/ref=dbs_a_def_rwt_bibl_vppi_i7  Doesn't cover modular forms, though.  He has a graduate text about modular forms, but it's much harder.